# Import JSON files into SQL Server 2016 as plain text without the use of function "OPENROWSET"?

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have no permission to use `bulk` and `openrowset`. Thus I am trying to find out alternative way to import JSON files into SQL Server as plain text without the use of `openrowset`, and then manipulate the data using `openjson`.

Comment: Do you have access to command-line osql or isql? From which, can you submit a sizable sql command to load the JSON into a table via a simple `INSERT INTO myTable (myJson) VALUES (' [....json file contents....]')`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have lots of json files which are scripted on line. It is impossible for me to manually type the content into sql table.